# How can i check the return value from web service using asynctask

Tags: android, web-services, android-asynctask

What i have is an asynctask that i use it to send data to web service which work just fine , and here is my web service code :

```
public class WebServiceDetails {
    //Namespace of the Webservice - can be found in WSDL
    private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    //Webservice URL - WSDL File location    
    //URL = "http://80.90.161.246:70/erP_Reporting/OrderAndroid.asmx";
    private static String URL = "http://192.168.1.124/alibabanewwebservice/AliBabaWebService.asmx";//Make sure you changed IP address
    //private static String URL = "http://192.168.1.103/webservicejal6ah/OrderAndroid.asmx";//Make sure you changed IP address
    //SOAP Action URI again Namespace + Web method name
    private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/InsertOrderDetails";

    public static boolean invokeLoginWS(String DeviceId, String Item_id, String Item_Quantity,String Bounce,String webMethName) 
    {
        boolean loginStatus = false;
        // Create request
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, webMethName);
        // Property which holds input parameters
        PropertyInfo deviceid = new PropertyInfo();
        PropertyInfo itemid = new PropertyInfo();
        PropertyInfo quantity = new PropertyInfo();
        PropertyInfo bounce= new PropertyInfo();


        deviceid.setName("DeviceId");
        deviceid.setValue(DeviceId);
        deviceid.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(deviceid);


        itemid.setName("Item_id");
        itemid.setValue(Item_id);
        itemid.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(itemid);


        quantity.setName("Item_Quantity");
        quantity.setValue(Item_Quantity);
        quantity.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(quantity);


        bounce.setName("Bounce");
        bounce.setValue(Bounce);
        bounce.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(bounce);

//        extra.setName("Extra");
//        extra.setValue(Extra);
//        extra.setType(String.class);
//        request.addProperty(extra);


        // Create envelope
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(1);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        // Set output SOAP object
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        // Create HTTP call object
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);


        try {
            // Invoke web service
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            // Get the response
//            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            Object response = (Object) envelope.getResponse();
            // Assign it to  boolean variable variable
            loginStatus = Boolean.parseBoolean(response.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Assign Error Status true in static variable 'errored'

            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        //Return booleam to calling object
        return loginStatus;
    }
}
```

And here is my asynctask :

```
private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {



    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
         Log.e("Customer_Name","sereen");
        //Make Progress Bar invisible


        //AddToCart.cartlist.clear();
        try{
             //Log.e(" Customer_Id=masterrs.get(m).getCustomerId()", rs.get(m).getCustomerId());
            Toast.makeText(CartList.this, "order has been send ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    //Make Progress Bar visible
    protected void onPreExecute() {
       super.onPreExecute();
        pd.setTitle("sending");
        pd.setMessage("waiting...");
        pd.show();
    }



    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


             loginStatus2 = WebServiceDetails.invokeLoginWS(Device_ID,Item_Id,Quantity,Bounce,"InsertOrderDetails");
             Log.e("Device_ID details",Device_ID+"");
//          try{
             //Log.e(" Customer_Id=masterrs.get(m).getCustomerId()", rs.get(m).getCustomerId());

//          }
//          catch(Exception e){
//              e.printStackTrace();
//          }
//          
//       }
         }


        return null;
    }
    }
```

well , the problem is as you can see my asynctask return null value and i want it after i send value to return true for (loginStatus2) but the thing is when i tried to do it , it didn't work .. can anyone help me , what shall i change to get the value true when success post on web service and false when it fails?

Comment: You are using `void onPostExecute` make its return type `boolean`

Comment: it gave me an error on : super.onPostExecute(loginStatus2);

Comment: it says : The method onPostExecute(Void) in the type AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> is not applicable for the arguments (boolean)

Comment: the syntax of Asyn Task is like this `final AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>` so make it ` AsyncTask<Void,Void,boolean>`

Comment: @ Sagar. This makes no sense. Don't change the return value of onPostExecute. It has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @sereen. An AsyncTask does not return a value. In onPostExecute you can do something with the value (as Crawler demonstrated). You could also start a new thread or asynctask or call a function. But not return a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code for AsyncTask. Use result and check if it is null or not.

If null, there is no response else you can have response in form of result from Asynctask() method.

```
private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
String response;


protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
     if(result==null){
        Toast.makeText(CartList.this, "result is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}else{
        Toast.makeText(CartList.this, "Result is: "+ result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    try{ //Your code here
         //Log.e(" Customer_Id=masterrs.get(m).getCustomerId()", rs.get(m).getCustomerId()); 
        Toast.makeText(CartList.this, "order has been send ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } 
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

} 


//Make Progress Bar visible 
protected void onPreExecute() { 
   super.onPreExecute(); 
    pd.setTitle("sending"); 
    pd.setMessage("waiting..."); 
    pd.show(); 
} 

@Override 
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 


         loginStatus2 = WebServiceDetails.invokeLoginWS(Device_ID,Item_Id,Quantity,Bounce,"InsertOrderDetails");
        response = loginStatus2;
         Log.e("Device_ID details",Device_ID+"");

     } 


    return response; 
} 
}
```